# ExoPlayer position the progress bar below the Player View

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Is there a way to position the `DefaultTimeBar` of the `ExoPlayer` below the `SimpleExoPlayerView` while keeping the play/pause and other controls in the center?

A good reference to what I'm trying to achieve UI wise is the YouTube player.

I am using a custom `controller_layout_id`. But I am stuck between the bounds of my parent which is the `SimpleExoPlayerView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using a custom `PlaybackControlView`. Just make sure to set the default control view to false

```
playerView.useController = false
```

Assign the custom `PlaybackControlView` your player instance

```
playerControls.player = player
playerControls.showTimeoutMs = autoHideMs
playerControls.show()
```

Works on ExoPlayer `2.6.0`

Comment: How to get realtime playing status. I want to play some videos or ad videos in a specific time (Eg. Play ad video in every 30 seconds). How to achieve this while using exoplayer.